# Using multiple database with same model in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

So I have multiple database. `DB_US` and `DB_UK`. They have the exact same structure but they hold data for different countries. I have an api with flask_restful. The endpoint accept a country to retrieve the data of this specific country.

My problem is I can't figure out how to select the database per request. I've read the bind method, but you have to specify a `__bind_key` per model and all my model are in both databases.

I've tried to initialize the database within the `@before_request`, but you can't call the `init_db` method (or any setup method) after the first request has been handled.

This is a particular case because the database are identical so it seems like it would make sense to have it in the same database, but it's part of a larger system and needs to be that way.

How could I select the database on a per request basis?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I've described it here [Using multiple POSTGRES databases and schemas with the same Flask-SQLAlchemy model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636447/using-multiple-postgres-databases-and-schemas-with-the-same-flask-sqlalchemy-mod)

Your cases is a little easier, because you don't have to deal with the schema differences.
You could do what stamaimer suggested, but the problem is created new User models for each country (and if you have more than 2, it just gets messy).

To fix it I stopped using the flask-sqlAlchemy db instantiation method and let the content provider init method handle which db to choose:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker()

class ContentProvider():

    db = None
    connection = None
    session = None

    def __init__(self, center):
        if center == UK:
            self.db = create_engine('sqlite://UK', echo=True, pool_threadlocal=True)
            self.connection = self.db.connect()
        elif center == US:
            self.db = create_engine('sqlite://US', echo=True, pool_threadlocal=True)
            self.connection = self.db.connect()
        self.session = Session(bind=self.connection)

    def index(country):
        user = models[country]["User"](username=country + str(time.time()))
        self.session.add(user)
        self.session.commit()
        return country, "added"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can define some base data models and inherit them for separate database. For example:

```
class User(db.Model):

    __abstract__ = 1

    # fields define

class UserUK(User):

    __bind_key__ = 'uk'

class UserUS(User):

    __bind_key__ = 'us'
```

You can create a dict which is `model = {"uk": {"User": UserUK}, "us": {"User": UserUS}}` to select proper model by country from request. For example: `model[country]["User"]`.

Full Demo:

```
import time
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////path/2/default.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_BINDS"] = {"uk": "sqlite:////path/2/uk.db", "us": "sqlite:////path/2/us.db"}

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class UserBase(db.Model):

    __abstract__ = 1

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=1)

    username = db.Column(db.String(16))


class UserUK(UserBase):

    __bind_key__ = "uk"


class UserUS(UserBase):

    __bind_key__ = "us"


models = {"uk": {"User": UserUK}, "us": {"User": UserUS}}


@app.route("/<country>")
def index(country):

    user = models[country]["User"](username=country + str(time.time()))

    db.session.add(user)

    db.session.commit()

    return country, "added"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=1)
```

Comment: I have had this structure for a long. This did work for previous versions of flask, sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy, but fails for latest versions (Since name of tables in all dbs are same, sqlalchemy throws an error 


"sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'account' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object."